# Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=2.0.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a' or one of its dependencies

Tags: dll, log4net

I looked at the similar questions, but couldn't find any that fitted my situation, or any answer that worked for my case.
My situation:

- Webapp that interfaces through dlls with a client-side application through API
- everything worked fine, until I had to create another version of the dlls to interface with a previous version of the client-side application, which use an older version of log4net (new version uses v2.0.12.0, older uses v2.0.8.0
- in this new version of the dlls, that use 2.0.8.0 as the application, when trying to call upon it in the Webapp, I get the error, claiming it tries to use log4net 2.0.12.0, but can't find it

I checked everything found in other answers and elsewhere:

- all references to log4net point to the version used by the application (so 2.0.8.0)
- all Nuget packages that use log4net also use 2.0.8.0 (one didn't, I corrected that, and that was 2.0.7.0 anyway)
- all the compilation caches were emptied
- checked the GAC, nothing there either
- the error is about the local dll, not the server-side webapp, so there should not be any issue with the 32/64 bits issue (it's 64 bits on both sides anyway)

So, in summary, nowhere in sight is there any mention of log4net 2.0.12.0 in the dlls, but any time the webapp tries to use any of them, it says 2.0.12.0 is requested but missing.

Now, for the part that really drives me crazy? The PublicKeyToken mentioned in the error message as being the one for 2.0.12.0... is actually the one for 2.0.8.0...

Any idea where I should look next?

EDIT: I now also tried using an AssemblyResolve to force the use of 2.0.8.0, but to no avail, it still tried to use 2.0.12.0...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally nailed what the root cause of the issue was: yet another service was launched in background to point the webapp to the correct folder, where to find the connector, and that service was made for the prior version of the main software.

As a result, the webapp was looking in the wrong folder, which contained an outdated version of the connector, and the main software was no longer there (uninstalled).

I understood all this when I decided to clean everything up, and restart from a clean install, with just the main software and the plugin, and no traces of any other version of either, not even the containing folders.

Thanks to anyone who looked into my issue!